# El parámetro lista no me esta pasando en el ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
'use strict';
function validacion(){
  var  regex = /[\w-\.]{2,}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/;
  var url = "heroku.com/";
  var lista = "loquesea";
  var data = {
    nombre: $("#nombre").val(),
    apellido: $("#apellido").val(),
    correo: $("#correo").val(),
    sexo: '', 
    educacion: '', 
    laboral: '', 
    pais: '', 
    ciudad: '', 
    nacimiento: '',
    cel: $("#cel").val(),
    id: '', 
    lista: lista
  };

  if(data.nombre == '' || data.nombre == null){
    $("#nombre").val(null);
    $("#nombre").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su Nombre");
    $("#nombre").focus();
  }

  if(data.apellido == '' || data.apellido == null){
    $("#apellido").val(null);
    $("#apellido").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su Apellido");
    $("#apellido").focus();
  }

  if (regex.test($('#correo').val().trim())) {

  } else {
    $("#correo").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su email");
    $("#correo").focus();
  }

  if(isNaN($('#cel').val())) {
    $("#cel").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su Celular");
    $("#cel").focus();
  }

  if($('#cel').val().length < 11) {
    alert('El teléfono debe tener 11 caracteres. Ej. 04121234567');
  }

  $.ajax({
    data: data,
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  });
}
```

Tengo esta función sin embargo cuando reviso el patrón de lo que envía ajax no veo el valor de lista

Comment: Podrias realizarlo por medio de peticiones ajax a tu servicio encargado de guardar los datos del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

El error 500 me da porque a pesar de que tenia un valor para una lista el estaba esperando el resultado desde el body, ahora bien tengo otro problema quiero enviar un ajax pero que se quede en la misma pagina.

Comment: Entonces esta es una respuesta o no ?

Comment: No se entiende nada de esta respuesta. Mira por favor [answer]. Resolviste tu problema? si es asi, como?

Comment: Si lo resolvi colocando un input como hidden con el nombre del valor del atributo que necesitaba enviar al servidor.